# I want to test json python

Tags: python, arrays, json, database

**I want to test  json python*

```
    for i in range(110):
      x ={
        int(i+i):"list"
      }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  If this code does not do what you want, explain.

Comment: @JohnGordon OP, I believe, has an issue with `"w"` flag, so their resulting file contains only one string. If they changed it to `"w+"`, I think they would get what they want.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak Then they should _explain_ that...  (And `w+` wouldn't solve that issue anyway.  Did you mean `a`?)

Comment: @JohnGordon ah, yeah, of course, I'm too sleepy :)

Comment: Why keep reading, appending, and saving the file 110 times? Just append to a string then overwrite that string into the file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while i < 110:
    i+=1
    res = f"x = {i}:'list'"
    json_object = json.dumps(res)
    with open("sample.json","a") as write_file:
        write_file.write(json_object)
```